# Is it possible to change the settings in NodeJS or the npm package nodemon to NOT display the [nodemon] messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[Screen shot of [nodemon] messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL4RX.png)

I want to remove the [nodemon] messages. If possible, how can I do this?

I would like it to operate like in the browser when in the console. Just less cluttered for simple things.
Although, I like the debugging part of it when needed.

Comment: what if you set verbose false as per the documentation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I actually found that node has a built in 'experimental' tool called --watch

https://gist.github.com/aidev13/e3c2ffab78f5611aa3e46e3f16238d61